# Creating layers from selection with while loop using PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, pyqgis, loop

I am trying to write a short snippet of code to break a shapefile up according to a specific attribute.

Here is my code:

```
from qgis.core import *
import processing
layer = processing.getObject('2012')
#counter is 15 due to limit  R15
counter = 1

# Write the while filter expression and set it
while (counter <= 15):
    selection = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression('"Group Comp" LIKE  \'R'+str(counter)+'\' '))
    layer.setSelectedFeatures([k.id() for k in selection])

    #Creates layer from selection
    _writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(i,r"E:\Scratch\test\NewFile"+str(counter)+".shp","utf-8",None,"ESRI Shapefile", True)
    counter = counter + 1
```

I get the following error in Qgis when running the above code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 5, in <module>
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

Is my selection of the layer incorrect?

Comment: You need to type `layer` instead of `i`. However, I'm not sure that the selection is applied in that way...

Comment: @mgri - You should post your _comment_ as an **answer** as the code works perfectly with the selection :)

Comment: @Joseph I was not sure about the using of while statement with that expression: did you run a similar test?

Comment: @mgri - Yes, I ran a test with the same field name and values. The output shapefiles were correct with the `while` loop =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get that error because you haven't defined `i` as a variable. Instead of `i`, you should specify the layer on which you are working.

You may try to use this code:

```
from qgis.core import *
import processing
layer = processing.getObject('2012')
#counter is 15 due to limit  R15
counter = 1

# Write the while filter expression and set it
while (counter <= 15):
    selection = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression('"Group Comp" LIKE  \'R'+str(counter)+'\' '))
    layer.setSelectedFeatures([k.id() for k in selection])

    #Creates layer from selection
    _writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer,r"E:\Scratch\test\NewFile"+str(counter)+".shp","utf-8",None,"ESRI Shapefile", True)
    counter = counter + 1
```

instead of what you have provided (I only changed `i` with `layer`).